# Seeking tutorials, books, papers, blogs, etc to handle spatial data in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, references

Does anyone know some good tutorials, books, papers, blogs, etc to handle spatial data in R?

I know that there are some packages like rgdal and maptools but I haven't actually found useful tutorials to get in touch with the basic functions (read, plot, change symbology, join data, etc.) and/or to get a broader overview what are the actual capabilities of R for spatial analysis and manipulation of Spatial data.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

There's quite a few resources for learning 'spatial' R online:

- [spatial-analyst.net](http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- A really solid [blog post](http://davenportspatialanalytics.squarespace.com/blog/2012/6/19/notes-from-a-recent-spatial-r-class-i-gave.html) by
  Frank Davenport, with [notes](http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/%7Eaedin/courses/R/CDC/broomspatial.pdf) on some basic spatial data manipulation in R
- [R Spatial Tips](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229204802/http://rspatialtips.org.uk:80/) (Internet Archive link, original site seems to be gone)
- [Barry Rowlingson's site](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Erowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/index.html) containing some great examples and a [cheatsheet](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Erowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html)
- I'd strongly recommend [Analysing spatial point patterns in 'R'](http://www.csiro.au/resources/pf16h)
  by Prof. Adrian Baddeley at the [CSIRO](http://www.csiro.au/) in Australia. It covers
  the [`spatstat`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html) module in depth and I think it's a great resource
  for cluster analysis.
- [Applied Spatial Data Analysis in R](http://www.springer.com/public+health/book/978-0-387-78170-9) (Bivand, Roger S., Pebesma,
  Edzer J., Gómez-Rubio, Virgilio) and [Spatial Statistics and
  Modeling](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-92256-0) (Gaetan, Carlo, Guyon, Xavier) are also both great
  books.
- Virgilio Gómez Rubio's (he is the author of the famous/superuseful ASDAR book, mentioned in other answers) [website](http://www.uclm.es/profesorado/vgomez/teaching/) provides materials to his tutorials from useR! conferences - slides, data and code are available.
- Apart from ADAR, there is now new book '*An Introduction to R for Spatial Analysis and Mapping*' by Brundson & Comber with [code available for download](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/an-introduction-to-r-for-spatial-analysis-and-mapping/book241031#resources).
- CSDE (University of Washington) course on GIS has [some spatial R](http://csde.washington.edu/services/gis/workshops/SPATIALR.shtml) materials, focusing on [ESDA](http://csde.washington.edu/services/gis/workshops/ESDA.shtml), [GWR](http://csde.washington.edu/services/gis/workshops/GWR.shtml), [spatial regression](http://csde.washington.edu/services/gis/workshops/SPREG.shtml)
- [Maps with R I](http://procomun.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/maps_with_r_1/) ([II](http://procomun.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/maps_with_r_2/), [III](http://procomun.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/maps_with_r_3/)) series of blog posts offer a lot of extensively commented code that you can learn from.
- UC Davis Soil Resource Laboratory has a [nice collection](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/book/export/html/519) of tips and examples of spatial R
- Francisco Rodriguez-Sanchez has a nice [materials](https://github.com/Pakillo/R-GIS-tutorial/blob/master/R-GIS_tutorial.md) on 'Spatial data in R: Using R as a GIS'.
- [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/) by T. Hengl
- [Comprehensive Tutorial for Spatio-Temporal R Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SpatioTemporal/vignettes/ST_tutorial.pdf) (Bergen et al., 2013)
- [ggmap: Spatial Visualization with ggplot2](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf) (Kahle and Wickham)
- D.G Rossiter ([lecture notes](http://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/teach/lecnotes.html#geostat))
- [Spatial.ly](http://spatial.ly/2013/12/introduction-spatial-data-ggplot2/)

A few nice tutorials, including some with a focus on interactivity (often listed as a weakness of doing GIS with R)

- [Spatial data in R: Using R as a GIS](http://pakillo.github.io/R-GIS-tutorial/): A tutorial to perform basic operations with spatial data in R, such as importing and exporting data (both vectorial and raster), plotting, analysing and making maps. by Francisco Rodriguez-Sanchez
- [Using RStudio as an interactive GIS with
  Leaflet](https://rpubs.com/walkerke/rstudio_gis) by  Kyle Walker,
  Texas Christian University
- [Working with PostGIS from R](http://rpubs.com/dgolicher/6373) by
  Duncan Golicher
- [Geospatial Data Processing and Analysis in
  R](http://rpubs.com/ajlyons/rspatialdata) by Andy Lyons

I also made a quick easy and holistic tutorial you folks can check out here [https://github.com/mattjbayly/MapsProj](https://github.com/mattjbayly/MapsProj/blob/master/Maps_Tutorial.R). All you need is the R text script and all other material is downloaded remotely from R.

My tutorial covered GIS data imports/exports, basic manipulation of vector & raster data, some of basic plotting and a brief overview of projections.
Estimated time to complete: 60mins

Answer (score 1):

I have some tutorials introducing spatial analysis in R on my website:

http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial

Answer (score 0):

Dr Alec Stephenson talk on Exploring spatial data with R: [Slides and scripts](http://files.meetup.com/1685538/Alec%20Stephenson%20Spatial%20Data%20Slides%20and%20Code.zip)

Comment: I find this very hard to grasp. It only has 4 slides that mainly say "look at these packages", and non-commented code that will give you examples, but leave all the research on what exactly this does to the reader.